# how to create array that sums values of another array? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays

say I have an array with the following ten values:
329,374,353,336,137,340,374,374,356,329
I want to create a new array which uses those values and creates a sum according to their position, so that the new array (based on those values) would look like so:

329, 329+374, 329+374+353, 329+374+353+336, ...
using javascript alone (no jquery) how can I achieve that?

Comment: Btw: there's **absolutely nothing** that jQuery can do and plain JS can't.

Comment: @Shomz - the OP is just requesting a plain Javascript answer (with no jQuery).  That's a very reasonable clarification of what is wanted.

Comment: @jfriend00, haha, had one ("jQ solves everything") about two minutes ago, so I know exactly what you mean. :) I just want the OP (and everyone else reading the comment) to be aware of that.

Comment: @Shomz I'm aware of that, that's why I never bothered learning jQ and have no intentions to do it in the near future. I just mentioned it, as jfriend00 said, so that I won't get answers in jQ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
input = [329,374,353,336,137,340,374,374,356,329]
output = [input[0]]
for (var i = 1; i < input.length; ++i){
    output[i] = output[i-1]+input[i];
}
```

Comment: you know, it's a funny thing, just as I submitted the question I suddenly had the idea of doing exactly what you suggested here. I went over to my testing site and it worked. then when I returned here and there were already 2 answers. I guess sleeping only 3 hours last night has taken its toll :)

Comment: @user3086182 - just curious why do you prefer a manual `for` loop over `.map()` which is built exactly for an iteration which creates a new array.

Comment: @jfriend00 TBH I don't think I fully understand what `.map()` does and I don't have time to delve into that at moment, so I go with the simpler solution which gets the job done...

Comment: @user3086182 - when you get some time, you should learn the built-in array functions like `.map()`, `.forEach()` and `.reduce()` as they can be very useful.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.map()` and a running total variable:

```
var array = [329,374,353,336,137,340,374,374,356,329], sum = 0;
var result = array.map(function(item) {
    sum += item;
    return sum;
});
console.log(result);
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/9ekkk1r3/

---

```js
var array = [329,374,353,336,137,340,374,374,356,329], sum = 0;
var result = array.map(function(item) {
    sum += item;
    return sum;
});

// show results in snippet
document.write("[" + result.join(',') + "]");
```

`.map()` is useful here because it both iterates through the source array and creates a new result array which is exactly what you want to do.  Then, all your have to do to simplify the result is to keep a running total of the sum so far so you know what to add for each new value.

Comment: @Shomz - I modified the snippet to output to the window directly rather than in an alert.  I'm not yet a fan of snippets myself, but I don't mind you put one in.